# Moving cursor in terminal using ESC sequences

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

I am writing a board game, in which I have to print some cards on screen. I have several classes for cards and method `print_card()` in every class.
Output of a card should be smth like this:
|C L|
|S D|
or other words in a square.

```
void ShipCard::print_card() {
    std::cout << "|SHP|\033[5D\033[1E|" << pirates_cnt << "  |\033[1A"; }
```

I use ESC sequence to move cursor. The problem is that when I try to print several cards one-by-one, the next one prints on the place of the previous, although I move the cursor back on top.
But if I print some text, not a card, it works normally.

Why it does not work properly? Is it possible to make it with only ESC sequences, without something like ncurses?

For example, if I use

```
std::cout << "|A B|\033[5D\033[1E|" << "C D|\033[1A";
```

and after:

```
std::cout << "|M N|\033[5D\033[1E|" << "O P|\033[1A";
```

I get:

|A B|
|O P|

instead of:

|A B||M N|
|C D||O P|

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Not only are Escape sequences extremely terminal specific, their interpretation is different from what is output by `cout` vs what is interactively entered by user.  The point of libraries such as ncurses is to allow you to ignore such specificity and focus on what you want output on your terminal screen.

Comment: Completely off the cuff: you send something that looks like SAME escape sequences, and expect the output to end up in a different place?